# Exporting TFIDF vectors from a lucene index into a human friendly format such as JSON

Tags: lucene, tf-idf

Is there an easy way:

1. Tool
2. Code fragment

To export TFIDF vectors from a lucene index into a human friendly format such as JSON. Preferred implementation languages are Java and Python.

Thanks.

NOTE:

1. My object here is not to debug/browse the index -- for that I can use Luke
2. My objective is to be able to dump the tfidf vectors into a more portable data format.

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to accomplish, exactly.  If you are looking for a diagnostic tool or some such, have you looked into [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/)?  Or do you really need a JSON                                                                                                                                            /etc for some reason?

Comment: @femtoRgon, thanks for the note -- I'm not looking for something like luke -- but rather exporting it in a format that is more common such as JSON.

Comment: In that case, you can access that information through [IndexReader.getTermVectors](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVectors(int)).

Comment: @femtoRgon I'll give that a spin -- if it works I'll post the code fragment as an answer. Thanks.